# How to promote secondary database in Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Running Rails 6 on Heroku-20 stack. We have our main production database, and then have provisioned a secondary database to act as our data warehouse. Initially the free tier of Postgres was used to host our data warehouse, and now we want to upgrade to the paid tier.

I've successfully copied the data from the free tier to the newly provisioned paid tier DB. Now I can't figure out how to promote the paid tier DB.

`heroku pg:promote` seems to only apply to the DATABASE_URL production DB.

When I try:
`heroku config:set WAREHOUSE_DATABASE_URL=postgres://xxxxx:xxxxxxxx@ec2-52-202-89-128.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/xxxxxxx`

I receive the error:

*Cannot overwrite attachment values WAREHOUSE_DATABASE_URL*

Comment: I've never seen `WAREHOUSE_DATABASE_URL` before, but that error messages suggests it is coming from an addon. Where does it come from?

Comment: It's the environment variable that points to our secondary warehouse database. In the database.yml its used for the warehouse database configuration.

Comment: Okay, but where does it _come from?_ It gets _referenced_ in your `database.yml`, right? What is supposed to set it?

Comment: Oh I see. The WAREHOUSE_DATABASE_URL was set by us. It's arbitrary. My assumption is that now that it's being used to point to a live database, we can no longer alter it.

Comment: I believe you should only get that message for addon-provisioned variables. Have you tried using the web dashboard? Does it give you the same error?